# challenge with router.navigate and localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I have a code that uses router.navigate to forward the user to a place

```
abrirLista(categoria, id) {
localStorage.setItem('categName', JSON.stringify(categoria));
const slug = slugify(categoria);
this.router.navigate(['/lista', 'categoria', slug], { queryParams: { id } });
}
```

as you can see it saves data in localstorage
with this other code I retrieve the data in Angular's ngOnInit, and do the interpolation in my html

```
getCategName(){
if(localStorage.getItem('categName')) {
    this.categName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('categName'))
}
}
 <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{categName}}</li>
```

the problem is that the `abrirLista` It's in a component in the header, so it doesn't update the page and doesn't enter ngOnInit to execute the function `getCategName`, so it can't update the variable `this.categName`

I made a button that updates, but the idea is that whenever I execute the function `abrirLista` he updated the variable, but I'm not able to see how to do it

```
  teste(){
   this.categName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('categName'))
  }
```

Comment: It's very hard to imagine what you build without live example, it is clear you need to communicate between different components and there are so many ways in angular to do that, service is one of them https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service If it is not what you ask, please share working code example so we don't need to guess how it works.

Comment: I think it's complicated to directly see the concern you have without having an environment to analyze. I recommend that you create a simple app with your piece of code.

Comment: You should use the localStorage.getItem function right within ngOnInit. It cannot be within a subscribe function inside ngOnInit. This was the mistake in my case

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do by using this browser API (localStorage) is to store data such that you persist it for the second component to consume it. However you do not have the right connection established between the components so they can communicate the change and update your view. Angular has its own mechanism for such purposes. You can use:

- Notifer and Listener (Observer pattern) with [RxJS Subjects](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).
  For this paradigm you need to use a service (Singelton pattern) class to setup the communication between the notifier and the listener components.
- [@Input and @Output](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) property and event binding to share data between components without a service